# How do I query of the current user permissions using REST Call on doesUserHavePermissions method?

Tags: permissions, rest

I would like to find out whether the current user has "Manage Lists" permission in the site or not. 
I could not find any example to perform such a query using REST API Calls.

The endpoint based on MSDN look like this:

http:////_api/web/doesUserHavePermissions(permissionMask)

However, what should I define as "permissionMask" parameter?

Can someone give me an example?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 7):

I haven't been able to find a way to use doesUserHavePermissions from REST so I use effectiveBasePermissions instead:

```
function checkPermissions() {
    var call = jQuery.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +
            "/_api/Web/effectiveBasePermissions",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }
    });

    call.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        var manageListsPerms = new SP.BasePermissions();
        manageListsPerms.initPropertiesFromJson(data.d.EffectiveBasePermissions);

        var manageLists = manageListsPerms.has(SP.PermissionKind.manageLists);

        var message = jQuery("#message");
        message.text("Manage Lists: " + manageLists);
    });
}
```